# $f(x)>0, f''(x)>0, 0<x<1, \int_0^1f(x)dx=1$, Prove: $\int_0^1|f(x)-t|dx\leqslant \frac{(1-t)^2+1}{2}, \forall t\in\mathbb R$

Tags: integration, analysis

> $\displaystyle f(x)>0, f''(x)>0, 0<x<1, \int_0^1f(x)dx=1$, Prove: $\displaystyle \int_0^1|f(x)-t|dx\leqslant \frac{(1-t)^2+1}{2},\quad \forall t\in\mathbb R$.

I have tried this:

$$\int |f-t|\leqslant\sqrt{\int (f-t)^2}=\sqrt{\int f^2-2t+t^2}$$
But I cannot handle the $\displaystyle \int f^2$ and it seems like have nothing to do with the goal.

And I have discussed 4 circumstances:
$f(x)\leqslant t, f(x)\geqslant t$, $g=f-t$ have 1, 2 roots. The first two are easy to prove, but I have no idea with the other two.

Is there any other inequality should be applied in this problem? Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The statement seems to be false.**

With
$$
f(x)=30(x-1/2)^4+\frac{9}{2}(x-1/2)^2+1/4
$$
and $t=1$, you can calculate to get
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=1
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1|f(x)-t|\,dx=\frac{27}{25}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\approx 0.68 > \frac{1}{2}=\frac{(1-t)^2+1}{2}.
$$
Moreover, it is clear that $f>0$ and $f''>0$  for $0<x<1$, so this is really a counter-example.

Comment: great counter-example...! Thanks a lot, I'll check this problem